# ADFS refuse spring-saml metadata

Tags: adfs2.0, spring-saml

`saml` with an `ADFS idp`.

idp metadata import in sp is working fine (/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml), i had to add idp metadata signature in spring-saml keystore but i found info in the guide for this, so no prob.

My problem is in idp refusing spring-saml metadata.

Idp administrator send me the exception:

```
Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust : ID6018: Digest verification failed for reference 
CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust], CryptographicException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ID6018: Digest verification failed for reference ...
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PS0132,Microsoft.IdentityServer.PowerShell.Commands.SetRelyingPartyTrustCommand
Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust : PS0132: No RelyingPartyTrust found with name ...
```

What do you think, SP certificate is self signed, and a sp metadata has signature in it.?
Do i have to remove the signature in the metadata or should the idp admin do something to avoid this error ?
thanks in advance
alessandro

Answer (score 2):

You should try two things:

- make sure your endpoints in SP metadata are using https endpoints
- regenerate SP metadata without signature, or remove the signature manually

Comment: regenerate SP metadata without signature worked, thanks